# Vipassana texts and books references request

Tags: vipassana, reference-request, books

I just read Allan Wallace's "The Attention Revolution: Unlocking the Power of the Focused Mind" book. He cites *vipashyana* (or vipassana, vipassanā, vipaśyanā, lha-thong) but he doesn't deepen much on it.

Can you refer to some texts and books regarding this meditation?

Comment: The best is that you do a course on meditation. There are many meditation centres as per different linages. If you are interested in meditation as taught by S.N.Goenka please visit: https://www.dhamma.org/ and register for a course. There are centres in many countries. The main thing about insight meditation is the practice  aspect which you cannot easily grasp from a book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Buddhanet](http://www.buddhanet.net/) contain a lot of meditation related [ebooks](http://www.buddhanet.net/ebooks_m.htm) on the topic which you can read. A good introductory book would be:

- [Essentials of Insight Meditation Practice](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/essentials.pdf)
- [MINDFULNESS IN PLAIN ENGLISH](http://www.wisdompubs.org/book/mindfulness-plain-english)
- [Right Mindfulness: Memory & Ardency on the Buddhist Path](http://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/right_mindfulness_v140930.pdf)

Also following questions on the site might be of interest also:

- [Introductory books to Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/60/introductory-books-to-buddhism)
- [Beginner academic text recommendation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/beginner-academic-text-recommendation)
- [Learning materials for Dependent Origination (Paṭiccasamuppāda) in Theravada Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/learning-materials-for-dependent-origination-pa%E1%B9%ADiccasamupp%C4%81da-in-theravada-bud)
- [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/english-or-other-european-translations-of-pali-canon)

Comment: Mindfulness in Plain English is great, and is freely available online: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/personal-development-workshops/mindfworkshop_resources/Mindfulness_in_plain_english

Comment: Thanks for the site. Following page gives more links if someone is interested: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/personal-development-workshops/mindfworkshop_resources

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/important-readings-in-vipassana/9046#9046. Should the questions be merged?

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Ingram's *"Mastering the Core Teachings of the Buddha"* is a superb reference for this. It also explains the differences between different forms of practice, which is useful for deciding when and if to do what. See [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1278/199) for more details. And the book itself is freely available from [Daniel's site](http://integrateddaniel.info/book/).

Answer (score 1):

[I have written an answer here which provides free books on the practice of *Vipassana medition*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/important-readings-in-vipassana/9046#9046).

All the books are written by the late Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw. You will find information about the practice of insight meditation, the fundamentals, the technique, development of insight etc. This might be of some help.

Lanka