# Important readings in vipassana

Tags: vipassana

I am looking for the most important Buddhist readings regarding vipassana teachings. I have read thoroughly the Satipatthana Sutta, but I wonder if there are other important texts regarding insight meditation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there are some great teachings by the burmese meditation master *Mahasi Sayadaw*.

[This website offers free books by Mahasi Sayadaw](http://www.yellowrobe.com/books/mahasi-sayadaw/237-books-by-mahasi-sayadaw.html) dealing with vipassana meditation and how to develop insight. This is a quote from the website regarding the free books:

> "The books in this section are free for downloads and personal uses. However, commercial uses are not allowed. The Buddha Sasana Online has acquired permission from Buddha Sasana Nuggaha Organization to post the books for free downloads as a gift for the Internet community. Therefore please keep these resources free, and if you wish to link to these files, please do not do so. Please copy the files to your own webspace, and save our bandwidth for other people. If you wish to distribute these books, you also need to ask permission from the publishers. Thank you".

You might find these books useful:

[**1. A Discourse on Vipassana**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/VIPASSANA.pdf)

An extensive guideline through the practice of Vipassana meditation and explanation of the Satipatthana medthod, including how Nibbana is realized through this method of practice.

[**21. Fundamentals of Vipassana Meditation**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/FUNDAMENTALS%20OF%20VIPASSANA%20MEDITATION.pdf)

This book includes an explanation of the difference of Samatha and Vipassana meditation, how Vipassana is practiced, the theory behind the practice, and how the practice achieves the goal of Nibbana and fulfills the Eightfold Noble Path.

[**26. Practical Vipassana Meditational Exercises**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/PRACTICAL%20VIPASSANA%20MEDITATIONAL%20EXERCISES.pdf)

This is a brief look to the Vipassana meditation along with a few exercises to begin with.

[**28. Purpose of Practicing Kammatthana (Buddhist) Meditation**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/PURPOSE%20OF%20PRACTISING%20KAMMATTHANA%20MEDITATION.pdf)

Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw explains the two kinds of meditations taught by the Buddha as well as a brief teaching on how to practice the two methods.

[**29. Satipatthana Vipassana Meditation**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/SATIPATTHANA%20VIPASSANA%20MEDITATION.pdf)

This book explains the Satipatthana Vipassana meditation method that's taught by the Buddha in the Satipatthana Sutta. It explains extensively the instructions given by the Buddha in the Satipatthana sutta, the practice, and the theory behind it.

[**30. Summary of Discourses on Purity and Insight (Visuddhi-Nana-Kattha)**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/VISUDDHI-NANA-KATTHA.pdf)

This is a collection of discourses given by the Ven. Mahasi Sayadaw on the subjects of purity and insight.

[**31. The Satipatthana Meditation**](http://www.yellowrobe.com/images/library/books/THE%20SATIPATTHANA%20VIPASSANA%20MEDITATION.pdf)

This is yet another discourse to extensively discuss the Satipatthana meditation method prescribed by the Buddha in the Satipatthana Sutta.

Lanka

Comment: 30+ discourses by Mahasi Sayadaw that can all be downloaded in one zip file:http://static.sirimangalo.org/mahasi/

Comment: The "Practical Insight Meditation" by Mahasi is easy to get in online bookshops and some people say it is the best dhamma-book ever ;)

Answer (score 3):

Following might be also of some use:

- Ledi Sayadaw

  - [THE VIPASSANA-DIPANI (The Manual of Insight) by Mahathera Ledi Sayadaw, Aggamahapandita, D.Litt.](http://mahajana.net/texts/kopia_lokalna/MANUAL01.html)
  - A collections of works: [The Manuals of Buddhism](https://ia700507.us.archive.org/19/items/LediSayadawManualOfBuddhism/LeDi-The-Manual-of-Buddhism.pdf)
- Webu Sayadaw:

  - [Way of Ultimate Calm](http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/publications/WebuSayadawDiscourses.pdf)
- Pa Auk

  - `Wisdom Wide and Deep: A Practical Handbook for Mastering Jhana and Vipassana by Shaila Catherine` - this is generally more accessible as well as comprehensive than other Pa Auk books. Other books can be obtained for free.
- Forest Dhamma: http://www.forestdhamma.org/books/english/
- Thanisaro Bhikku: http://www.dhammatalks.org/ebook_index.html (multiple good books)
- Achan Brahm:

  - `MINDFULNESS, BLISS, AND BEYOND`
- Bhante Vimalaramsi : http://library.dhammasukha.org/books.html
- [Bhante Henepola Gunaratana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henepola_Gunaratana) : Many good books on Insight meditation. See: http://www.amazon.com/Bhante-Henepola-Gunaratana/e/B002LADY6O