# What is the basic literature for becoming a buddist?

Tags: learning-materials, beginner, literature

I have been listening to free buddhist audio (FBA) podcast and have watched some videos about buddhism but i would like to see some introductory literature. Where to start?

Comment: Welcome to Buddhism SE! A similar question has already been asked and answered [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/60/408). Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thanks that was just what I was looking for. Apparently not well enough initially.

Comment: The answer I found most fitting was http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1613/582