# List of Buddhist podcast recommendations

Tags: learning-materials

This is in the spirit of this (previously requested) [List of book recommendations](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25889/254)

Books are wonderful for learning (and audio books are great travel partners/work listening), but I wondered if those of you who listen to podcasts could suggest a Buddhist podcast that serves your learning style.

Please include:

- a link to it,
- a few words about what it brings you (or a description, as you like)
- If it is in a language other than English please mention it to help those who would prefer to listen in a language in which they are more fluent.

I would prefer only a list of the ones you like/recommend.

thank you

MODERATOR's MESSAGE: please post one podcast per answer, so people can vote for each podcast individually.

Answer (score 3):

**Ajahn Brahm** - Based out of Australia. There are a few others that upload on the BSWA channel. The talks are very easy to follow. Ajahn Brahm is one of the more entertaining monks, as he brings comedy and jokes into his talks. What I personally enjoy about this channel is that the videos are labeled very well, so you can search for topics that you want to learn. Say you're having a difficult day and aren't positive you can search the channel for "staying positive" and there will be several videos on the subject.

Resources:

- Meditation Videos: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ajahn+brahm+guided+meditation
- Talks: https://www.youtube.com/user/BuddhistSocietyWA/search?query=Dhamma+Talk
- Channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6M_EhnSSdTG_SXUp6IAWmQ

Answer (score 1):

I like Master YongHua, he explains the Dharma in a way that makes it accessible to laypeople; he also has a great sense of humor and talks about topics that I don't find covered anywhere else. He has alot of videos on English and Vietnamese, take a look:

https://www.youtube.com/user/MasterYongHua/videos

Answer (score 1):

**Jack Kornfield** - Based out of California. His talks are uploaded to the following channel. He has several very good talks on compassion and developing the heart.

Resources:

- Talks: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqGJSfj5N-pIrpWHP9ITJzmyK8UDHJGzM
- Channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCc1lvEoC5PZWm-MzgUfJQfg

Answer (score 1):

**Alan Watts** - Not a formal monk, but he has several philosophical discussions that complement the study of the dharma.

Resources:

- Videos: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Alan+Watts

Answer (score 1):

I listen to **Chogyam Trungpa's** teachings up on [chronicleproject.com/teachings](https://www.chronicleproject.com/teachings/)

There are both [audio](https://www.chronicleproject.com/category/teachings/chogyam-trungpa-teachings/audio-of-chogyam-trungpa/) and [video](https://www.chronicleproject.com/category/teachings/chogyam-trungpa-teachings/video-talks/) talks.

They also have [a number of podcasts](https://www.chronicleproject.com/chronicles-radio/) from students and related people connected with Trungpa Rinpoche's lineage.

Answer (score 1):

i listen to this channel most of the time but most of the programmes are in sinhala but there are english ones too.

[Shraddha TV](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu7cGbQEMgGk8TD0ZYucM5g?pbjreload=10)

Answer (score 1):

[Tricycle podcast](https://tricycle.org/podcast/) - Also available on Apple podcasts/Itunes. Tricycle is a Buddhist magazine.

[Wisdom podcast](https://learn.wisdompubs.org/podcast/) - Available on Apple podcasts/Itunes and Spotify. Its a well known Buddhist book publisher.

[Dharmapunx NYC podcast](https://dharmapunxnyc.podbean.com/) - Available on Apple podcasts also. Dharmapunx is a New York City community with Theravada flavour to it. Its led by Josh Korda.

Answer (score 0):

**Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu** - former moderator of Buddhism.SE and is based out of Canada. His videos include in-depth discussions of the Dhamma.

Resources:

- Videos: https://www.youtube.com/user/yuttadhammo/videos and https://video.sirimangalo.org/