# How to reconcile non-attachment in a Type-A, North American culture where work is life?

Tags: reference-request, modern-world, science, attachment, technology

I've been meditating on-and-off for years.

However, the non-attachment preached by the Buddha conflicts with the environment around me. I'm in a large urban center in North America.

Achievement is valued; I feel like I'm contributing to the world in a small way.

I feel like it makes me better at my job to dream big and get attached to goals big and small, whether it's mentoring someone junior or committing years to a project that has an uncertain payoff.

This puts me at odds with my meditation practice, where "letting go" is emphasized.

The best resource I have found specifically addressing this question is Stephen Batchelor's book "After Buddhism". In it, Batchelor lays out one possible interpretation of the scriptures, in which the Buddha and his disciples are very much 'in the world'---businesspeople, merchants, town doctors, etc.---this was refreshing to read and made me feel more at ease.

Am I asking to eat my cake too? I value Buddhism and meditation, but I also value my Western individualist roots and feel egoistic achievement is necessary for progress in science and technology.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I am very much against this pop-culture Buddhism where too much emphasis is given to letting go and not that much emphasis on Bhavana and development of wholesome qualities. Letting go of what, exactly? Definitely, check out Thanissaro Bhikkhu's talks on YouTube who shares a similar opinion. There are many things which we need to let go: anger, jealousy, rage, covetousness, stinginess, delusion etc. There are many things we need to develop or "acquire": Metta, Compassion, Euqanimity, Mindfulness, Patience, Humility, Wisdom etc. Knowing which qualities are wholesome and developing them and which are unwholesome and letting go of them is practical wisdom.

Why does achievement need to be egoistic? Why not process and vision driven? We can always frame "achievements" as something bringing long term happiness to ourselves and the people around us instead of something "I" have added to my shining Resume. If that is the case, then no need to hesitate in pouring our energies into it; unless you realise later that this is not really the case.

A very interesting Theravada list is the four Iddhipada (four bases of mental power) cultivated for success in spiritual practice but equally applies in lay achievements. They are Chanda (Desire or Aspiration), Viriya (Energy), Citta (Keeping the Goal in mind), Vimansa (Review or Investigation of results to adjust). So, the Buddha is not against being competent, efficient and energetic in achieving your goals. Quite the opposite, he encourages it.

Also, don't worry about ego too much. Even third path Anagamis have conceit. It is a very deep fetter. So, don't be too worried about it as long as you are aware of it. Even, Ananda the Buddha's attendant once mentioned that we use conceit to overcome conceit (for example to be regular in practice), and moderation in eating to overcome sense desire. Otherwise, you would be going to the extreme of self mortification, which is ignoble and of little benefit.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be very distinct whether your attachment is towards:
1. Your positive influence to the world;
2. Your reward, no matter big or small;
3. Your egotistic sense of success; and/or
4. Your self/improvement, enlightenment, etc.

If you are towards 1-3, you are not achieving enlightenment.
If you feel you are towards 4 but you are not reducing any suffering, you are not achieving enlightenment either.

Remember, enlightenment is not just about letting go, but void of suffering. Are you following the 4 noble truths? and the 8 folds paths in what you do?

And by the way, egoistic achievement is NOT necessary for progress in science and technology. You can say it is a motivation for some people, but it is not the only possible motivation. Therefore, the "individualistic roots" are neither permanent nor necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Acharya Nagarjuna's advice:](https://studybuddhism.com/en/tibetan-buddhism/original-texts/sutra-texts/letter-to-a-friend)

> .... Don’t have as objects of your
>   mind the eight transitory things of the world: namely, material gain
>   and no gain, happiness and unhappiness, things nice to hear and not
>   nice to hear, or praise and scorn. Be indifferent (toward them).

Your question strikes me as wondering if it is possible to make progress towards liberation while maintaining the same level of attachment to the [Eight Worldly Concerns.](https://studybuddhism.com/en/advanced-studies/science-of-mind/emotional-hygiene/strategies-for-dealing-with-the-eight-worldly-concerns) I'm afraid the answer is no. What are the eight worldly concerns?

- Hoping for material gain (money, things, materialism)
- Fear of material loss (not wanting to lose your stuff)
- Striving for worldly happiness (many forms, but all temporary and ultimately unsatisfactory...)
- Fear of wordly unhappiness (not getting what we want in terms of above...)
- Desiring people to say nice things (aka, how awesome we are)
- Aversion to receiving criticism from others (how dare they!)
- Wanting others to like us (our reputation is so important)
- Fear that others won't like like us (being shunned)

Can progress be made toward liberation without requisite decline of the hold these concerns have on us? Here is what [Lama Zopa Rinpoche](https://www.lamayeshe.com/shop/how-practice-dharma) has to say:

> It is very easy to do Dharma activities such as reciting mantras,
>   saying prayers, making offerings and things like that with the thought
>   of the eight worldly dharmas. That happens. But in reality, the holy
>   Dharma, which includes all these activities, actually means renouncing
>   this life. Therefore holy Dharma and worldly dharma can never be done
>   together. **Nobody can do these two things—renounce this life and seek
>   the happiness of this life with the eight worldly dharmas—at once.** We
>   can do one and then the other but never both together in the one mind
>   at the same time.

Emphasis mine. Merely becoming aware of the eight worldly concerns and familiarizing with the idea that these are hindrances to be overcome is itself *some* progress. Which is to say that one mustn't completely eliminate attachment towards these concerns before one can *start to make any progress!* Rather, you shouldn't fool yourself into believing that progress can be made while *ignoring* these hindrances or worse thinking these hindrances aren't in fact hindrances.

Making progress in eliminating attachment to these worldly concerns is concomitant with making progress towards liberation.

It is a hard answer, but hopefully worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

> *However, the non-attachment preached by the Buddha conflicts with the environment around me. I'm in a large urban center in North America.*

In North America & in the West, some people even treat Buddhism itself (and teaching Buddhism) as a business (for making money). I would suggest to not take to heart everything you might hear and read, because the heart of Buddhism is beyond the reach of the average person.

> *Achievement is valued; I feel like I'm contributing to the world in a small way.*

Worldly achievement is required to earn a living or livelihood.

> *I feel like it makes me better at my job to dream big and get attached to goals big and small, whether it's mentoring someone junior
>   or committing years to a project that has an uncertain payoff.*

Sure. The attitude above shows why you should not allow Buddhist theory to confuse your ordinary & natural thinking processes. Buddhism used inappropriately in the wrong contexts may lead to confusion. It is best for us to avoid getting confused & illogical. This also leads to not harming Buddhism.

> *This puts me at odds with my meditation practice, where "letting go" is emphasized.*

Buddhist meditation is for ending suffering rather than for achieving worldly goals.

> *The best resource I have found specifically addressing this question is Stephen Batchelor's book "After Buddhism". In it, Batchelor lays
>   out one possible interpretation of the scriptures, in which the Buddha
>   and his disciples are very much 'in the world'---businesspeople,
>   merchants, town doctors, etc.---this was refreshing to read and made
>   me feel more at ease.*

Stephen Batchelor is I think an example of what I described above; of trying to commercialise "Buddhism" in a way which harms the Buddhist teachings, by attempting to make Buddhism relevant for people that Buddhism is not actually relevant for.

> *Am I asking to eat my cake too? I value Buddhism and meditation, but I also value my Western individualist roots and feel egoistic
>   achievement is necessary for progress in science and technology.*

I would suggest to simply give up any trendy aspects of your interest in Buddhism, including that book of Stephen Batchelor's.

For example, if scientists find a cure for AIDS or Cancer, there will be a great celebration in society. It will become the most trendy news. However, if this occurs, this does not mean you should take the AIDS or Cancer medicine cure if you do not have AIDS or Cancer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment–I understand you disagree with Stephen Batchelor's book, and similar "Western Buddhist" thought. 

Do you have a resource or recommendation where I might learn what you find valuable in Buddhist thought? Of a better framework for thinking about these kinds of things? 

My interest in Buddhism has been valuable personally and to those around me, so I'd love to hear more about your perspective before giving up my interest :)

Comment: Buddhism has teachings for laypeople and teachings for monks. The teachings for laypeople do not revolve around "non-attachment" or four noble truths. Therefore, it is not necessary to pervert the teachings of non-atachment, four noble truths, etc, so they somehow suit lay people. This link summaries the teachings for laypeople from the Pali suttas: https://www.mahidol.ac.th/budsir/Contents.html

Comment: Voted down for the ad-hominem attacking on Stephen Batchelor and the general disparagement of entire sangha jewel in the West. At a minimum, the answer should be clarified to use less absolute language regarding the motivation of Buddhists in the West and the ad-hominem on Stephen Batchelor.

Comment: I edited this to try to make it less disrespectful by making it more specific. For example the previous version could be read as disparaging all Buddhists and Buddhism in general, everyone and everywhere in America and in the West, whereas I think you want to warn against a more specific phenomenon (i.e. commercialising it, and altering it towards a different audience and purpose).

Comment: @lifer You might like [this book](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25963/254), too. It too starts by observing that some suttas are intended for lay people, and it organises and summarises the (bookful of good) advice in these suttas about the lay life: including business and money and partnerships and so on.

Comment: @ChrisW thanks. The language is less all encompassing. However, I think the parts critical of Batchelor are unwarranted and harmful. The OP posted he found something Stephen Batchelor said as useful to his mind. The language in this answer was made to disabuse the OP from relying upon Batchelor by criticizing him outside of the specific ideas that the OP found useful. If the answerer disagrees with the *ideas* that the OP said he found useful, then the answer should be edited to find fault with those *ideas* and not Batchelor. Otherwise, all mention of Batchelor should be dropped.

Comment: I thought that the criticism of Batchelor was: on-topic (relevant to the question); specific (not just "it's bad" but "it's commercialising and adapting"); criticising the person's work[s] more than the person; and relevant to the overall thesis (that the OP would get better advice, that the advice would be more Buddhist, if the advice were based more closely on the suttas). Maybe I'm becoming over-inured to rudeness? But it seems to be normal for Dhammadhatu's answer to disagree somewhat with the interpretation of a published author or translator. You're not required to agree with the answer.

Comment: I have many disagreements with Batchelor.  However, the OP has said in his question that Batchelor’s book was helpful to him and gave a synopsis of what he found helpful, e.g, that lay folks can feel free to participate in the world etc., what’s more this answeer seems to *agree* with that message! The big difference is the answerer apparently doesn’t believe Batchelor is a good messenger. That’s highly problematic and potentially harmful wrong speech. If the answerer has a problem with the message, then spell it out. That is apparently not the case. @ChrisW

Comment: I am very wary of and sensitive to people trying to disabuse others of reliance on their teachers. It is disrespectful and arrogant at best and actively harmful at worst. Leads to bad feelings and can turn people away from what they have found helpful. Like you said in another comment, there are many paths and teachings for everybody and to claim monopoly is arrogant. Now, if people espouse certain viewpoints, ideas, doctrines that people disagree with them then please feel free to spell out the disagreements! But questioning authenticity of people the OP has said they find helpful is too far.

Comment: The only thing that makes Batchelor relevant here is the view that some Suttas can be interpreted as agreeing that, “the Buddha and his disciples are very much 'in the world'---businesspeople, merchants, town doctors, etc.” if dhammadatu disagrees with this message, then he can say so and provide alternative view with reasons. That would be very much relevant to answering the question. Not trying to pour water on Batchelor as valid teacher while leaving the message unaddressed.

Comment: @Yeshe, you're technically right, but over the last few years we kinda noticed it works best to be somewhat tolerant to intolerance. Meaning, it's good to stop someone when they are being a total ass, but sometimes it's almost better to leave it be, especially when it comes to people's opinions on what is right dharma /  wrong dharma, you know? I value your participation, but let's try and make sure our efforts toward reducing conflict are not inadvertently increasing it, if you know what I mean... I think Chris softened the language enough for it to be a passable opinion. Let's move on?

Comment: I'm going to let this sit for awhile and think about it. To me this goes to a question of whether site moderators should correct harmful speech when it is flagged. I personally would like to have it pointed out if/when I am speaking harmfully and given a chance to correct. Moreover, if I'm incapable of seeing the harm my speech does I'd consider it a kindness for others to prevent that harm or help mitigate it by removing it. I have personally witnessed the harm that criticizing teachers (even if seemingly warranted) can have on a student of that teacher and lead away from Dharma @AndreiVolkov

Comment: Fair enough. Let's let it marinate.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is totally reconcilable. Not just "reconcilable", Buddhism is the best part of Type-A attitude taken to its logical conclusion.

If you think about it, Siddhartha himself used to be a typical Type-A person: highly ambitious, driven to success, unhappy with status-quo.

In my opinion, the more a Type A person optimizes his or her behavior to achieve their own definition of success, the more they will look like an enlightened Buddhist. And vice versa, the more a Buddhist realizes the teaching in practice, the more they will behave like a (purified, enlightened version of) a good business leader - strong, happy, confident.

Per my live teachers, non-attachment in Buddhism IS NOT cultivation of meekness. It is cultivation of unsinkable optimism and wise flexibility of mind.

(Mahayana) Buddhism is not against achievements either, it just offers the ultimate, more meaningful Achievement for those who are up to the challenge. My teacher said, this world is a perfect gym to train our Enlightened Mind qualities, so take it as such.

Buddhism may be at odds with small-minded, egoistic, fearful, greedy, aggressive attitude of some people - but these attitudes are not approved by the modern civil society either. So we are in complete sync with the spirit of times, I think - and should not be afraid to expose our Buddhist values to the public. IMO to be an open Buddhist would be  beneficial for society these days.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. To my mind it seems entirely consistent with avoiding the eight worldly concerns. For instance, how can one generate true confidence while worrying about reputation or trying to avoid criticism?